# performing logic in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database of files including the file id, size, location ect... 
The filesize is in bytes. I'd like to convert it to a friendly size at the same time that I select the information from the database. I'm using dynamic sql.  Is something like this possible (I know this is bad SQL and will not even come close to working, i'm just trying to show what I would like to happen):

```
declare @num bigint;
select @sql = @sql + 'select Id as ID, Name, Path, '@num = 'filesize, UserName from Files '
while (@num >= 1024)
 begin
   @num = @num / 1024
 end
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. I know I could just do this in the code rather than SQL but I'm concerned it may be too slow.

Comment: You could create a function to calculate the file size.

Comment: @PatrickHofman can you provide a small example so I see what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `CASE`:

```
select 
  Id as ID, 
  Name, 
  Path, 
  CASE 
    WHEN filesize >= 1024*1024*1024
      THEN filesize / (1024*1024*1024) + " GB"
    WHEN filesize >= 1024*1024
      THEN filesize / (1024*1024) + " MB"
    WHEN filesize >= 1024
      THEN filesize / (1024) + " KB"
    ELSE filesize
    END
    AS filesize,
  UserName
```

But honestly this is the responsibility of the display layer instead of SQL. I can't imagine it would be any slower to do it in code.

Comment: I would advise the OP to use a computed column for this transformation.  I'm also surprised this answer was accepted as is, because it should generate a type conversion error.  You need to convert the numeric values to a string so the `+` is interpreted as concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetUserFriendlySize (@i bigint)
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
  declare @output varchar(100);

  if @i >= 1024*1024*1024
  begin
      set @output = convert(varchar, @i / (1024*1024*1024)) + ' GB'
  end
  else if @i >= 1024*1024
  begin
      set @output = convert(varchar, @i / (1024*1024)) + ' MB'
  end
  else if @i >= 1024
  begin
      set @output = convert(varchar, @i / (1024)) + ' KB'
  end
  else
  begin
      set @output = convert(varchar, @i) + ' B'
  end
  return @output
end
GO
```

Then call it like this:

```
select dbo.GetUserFriendlySize(1999)
```

(actual logic from [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley))